# Method invocation 'extras' may produce NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Why does this cause the error?

```
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.getString("ActionBar") != null) {
        if (extras.getString("ActionBar").equals("NO")) {
            if (bar != null) bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I check to make sure that it is not null first.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `extras` itself is not `null`?

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, that was a mistake when posting code

Comment: Is it an error? It looks like a warning from your IDE.

Comment: @osundblad its a IDE Warning but I would still like to remove it

Comment: @spenf10 which line are you getting the warning on? I could maybe understand the `if (extras.getString("ActionBar").equals("NO")` since it might be to complex for the IDE to catch? If so you could remove the prior null check and just do `if ("NO".equals(extras.getString("ActionBar"))` which would be doing the null check implicitly.

Comment: @spenf Old question but was it maybe that `extras` was not final? If not it might change to null after the null check.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `extras.getString("ActionBar")` *twice*. Once you check the `return`ed value against `null` (but never use it) and once you use it without checking it against `null`. Now, *maybe* the contract of that function says that if it is called with identical arguments, it will always `return` identical values, but this need not be the case and your IDE probably doesn't know.

You should store the `return` value in a (preferably `final`) variable, then the warning should go away.

```
if (extras != null) {
    final String actbar = extras.getString("ActionBar");
    if (actbar != null) {
        if (actbar.equals("NO")) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This might also be a performance advantage because you don't need to do `getString`'s work twice.

Anyway, if your code is full of such massive aggregations of `if (o != null) { … }` checks, this might be an indication of [code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements).

Answer (score 1):

You get the **warning** because you may not receive any `bundle` (from the sender `activity` e.g) since you don't initialize it in the current context (or `activity`). So in this case, if you don't check if `extras` is `null` (and `extras` was in deed equal to `null`), this line:

```
if (extras.getString("ActionBar") != null)
```

would throw a `NullPointerException`. Therefore, you must check if `extras` is null first to avoid any potential crash.

Comment: Sorry I for got to include in code I pasted, first I do check that `extras != null`

Comment: @spenf10 what is your question then ?

Comment: Why do I still have this warning

Comment: Show me your code, where you're actually trying this.